# How to type accented characters in Ubuntu 10.04 with an Apple Aluminum Keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

I installed the latest Ubuntu 10.04 and I used to have the Command, Option or Right-Ctrl keys as compose keys to write accented characters. But I find that under Ubuntu 10.04, the Compose Key is not working, even if I specify the proper Apple Keyboard. Since I cannot work with other keyboard layouts than the plain USA one along with compose keys (I never learned, and I hate, the French layout), this about my only way to input accented characters.

I still have to try it with a regular keyboard to see whether there is a difference.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This describes how to set up a compose key in gnome:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey

hope it helps!